# How do I make a newline with python in a messageBox through wxPython?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

"\n" doesn't work for me here, going to say that before anyone suggests it.

I am currently working on a dialog message, which works fine. It shows an OK button with an information icon. In the dialog, (or messageBox), I am outputting an array of strings, but the issue is that these string don't start on a newline so the dialog looks a little messy. Here's an example:

```
myArray = ["Bananas", "Apples", "Pears", "Mangos"]

def showMessagebox():
   gui.messageBox(myArray, "Juicy fruits", wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
```

the output then does:

```
Bananas Apples Pears Mangos
```

Even when I put a "\n" before them! I also tried putting an "\n" after them, it won't work! It is actually including the "n" within the string! Not what I want. What I actually want is:

```
Bananas
Apples
Pears
Mangos
```

Doing something like `"\n bananas"` or `"bananas \n"` doesn't work. I assume that's because it's a messageBox. I want to know what will work! Help is greatly appreciated thank you =)

For demonstration, here's a screenshot of the dialog
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in a list instead of a string. Try

```
gui.messageBox('\n'.join(myArray), "Juicy fruits", wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
```

instead.

Comment: Check out my answer above, the result is very funny and interesting. The next thing I tried was doing "\n".join(bananas) and that outputted a bunch of n's next to the string

Comment: If that's the result you get then the code in your question isn't the code you're running. What you're seeing in your screenshot is the result of converting the list to a string and then doing `'\n'.join(str)` on *that*. Note the square brackets at the start and the end, they're because you're using the string representation of the list.

Comment: I also just tried to put "\n".join("bananas") on the string literal. It got me the same messed up result from the screenshot below

Comment: Yes you're correct, I converted the array to a string because the messageBox doesn't allow an array as an argument. It only accepts a string as an argument, so I had to use str() on the array

Comment: For the same reason. "bananas" is already a string, so running `'\n'.join` on it will add a `\n` between each character. Doing `'\n'.join(["Bananas", "Apples", "Pears", "Mangos"])` will give you each item with a `'\n'` between.

Comment: My solution is the way to convert the list to a string in the way you want, instead of just calling str() with it. To be clear, if the code you provide in your question is different to the code you have a problem with then the answer can't address the part we don't see.

Comment: I get this error 

 gui.messageBox( "\n".join(myArray), "Items properties", wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
TypeError: sequence item 7: expected str instance, builtin_function_or_method 

found` when I remove the str() from the array

Comment: As it says, the seventh item in your list is not a string. Try printing the list to the console so you can see what is in it. If you really need to include things in the list that aren't strings then a quick hack is to do `"\n".join([str(x) for x in myArray])`, but it's best to find out why you have strange things in there first.

Comment: Kemp, check out my edited answer up there. You helped me solve it! Thanks a lot